# MIT's Lecture 1: Algorithmic Thinking, Peak Finding - How does this Divide & Conquer Algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, conditional-statements, pseudocode, divide-and-conquer

I am looking at the lecture at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtSuA80QTyo&list=PLUl4u3cNGP61Oq3tWYp6V_F-5jb5L2iHb,from 27:22 - 32:50, particulary 28:17 to 31:01 where the teacher explains the divide-and-conquer algorithm for finding a peak in an array:

[image]

> Divide and conquer:
>
> ```
>    1     2         n/2-1  n/2  n/2+1        n-1    n
> ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
> │     │     │ ... │     │     │     │ ... │     │     │
> └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
>                            ↑
>                          Look at n/2 position
> ```
>
> if `a[n/2] < a[n/2-1]` then only look at left half `1...n/2-1` to look for a peak.
>
> Else if `a[n/2] < a[n/2+1]` then only look at right half `n/2+1...n` to look for a peak.
>
> Else `n/2` position is a peak.

I don't quite understand the above `if...else` logic.

If we take the first if/else case, why does the teacher claim that the left side has the peak, and the right side is to be discarded; and vice versa?

I thought that `if a[n/2] < a[n/2 - 1]` means that because it's false that `a[n/2]` is less than `a[n/2 - 1]`, then there for the values on the left shall be false rather than it being section to find the peak, and for the right and the other way around.

To clarify, if the values after the `n/2 + 1` or before `n/2 - 1` are false, then why are they true according to the video? And if the `if` statements are false, why do they still run, based upon him saying "then", then proceeding to show the results in text, even though they are false?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you want to point out as problematic, so I'll just focus on the algorithm itself:

First of all, the definition of a peak: this is a position whose corresponding array value is not less than any of its direct neighbor(s). Positions at the extreme left or right of the array can also be peaks: the condition then applies only to their only neighbor. (This is explained in the video in minute 17).

Some things to understand from this definition:

- Every non-empty array has a peak
- There can be multiple peaks
- When in a divide-and-conquer algorithm we choose one side to continue the search, it doesn't mean that there couldn't also be a peak in the half we are discarding. It just means we are *sure* to find a peak in the half we choose.

It may help to just look at a concrete example, and the possibilities of how the three middle elements then compare to each other. The three middle elements are those at indices /2−1, /2, and /2+1. Let's look at a few concrete possibilities, one at a time:

1. the middle three values are 31, 27, 18

   In this case the first `if` condition is true, and the algorithm says to look at the left half of the array for a peak. This is reasonable, because that 31 *could* even be a peak, and if not, then we can be sure to find a peak somewhere at the left of it, in the most extreme case at the extreme left side of the array. On the other hand, if we were to go right, we might be unlucky and only find that the values keep decreasing, so that there is no peak to be found there.
2. the middle three values are 18, 27, 31

   In this case the first `if` condition is false, and we should check the second `if` condition: that condition is true. The algorithm says to look at the right side for a peak. The reasoning is the same as in the previous case -- it is the mirrored scenario.
3. the middle three values are 18, 31, 27

   In this case neither the first nor the second `if` condition is true. By consequence we know that the middle value is a peak (by definition of what a peak is)